# Pandas Removing Duplicate Rows When Merging Two CSV's with Different Dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have been searching for a solution to this problem and all of the answers do not seem to be working so I decided to ask for help on this specific use case. I am merging two csv's that have different dimensions but share two equal columns. I first placed the csv's into a pandas dataframe which look like this:

df_td and df_ld:

```
>>> df_td.head(2)
   trans_id  store_num  cust_id               bus_date          type
0   0000001        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment
1   0000002        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment 
2   0000003        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Received



>>> df_ld.head(2)
   cust_id  nxt_date  store_num   amt_received           type_rec 
0   111111  11/5/2017       104          10.00            NaN
1   111112  11/6/2017       104          10.00            NaN
```

After running this code:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_td, df_ld, how='inner', on=['cust_id','store_num']).fillna(0)
```

I have this merged dataframe:

```
>>> df_td_ld.head(3)
   trans_id  store_num  cust_id               bus_date          type    nxt_date    amt_received    type_rec
0   0000001        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment    11/5/2017          10.00     NaN
1   0000002        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment    11/5/2017          10.00     NaN
2   0000003        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Received   11/5/2017          10.00     NaN
```

As you can see I get dups in the df_ld columns since the cust_id 111111 only appears once in that dataframe. IF I try so query and sum that column it will report 30.00 instead of the correct 10.00 on that date, for that customer, at that store. I have tried `outer` , `left` , `right` as well as `concat` and `join` functions but either get the same output or something completely wrong.

What I would like is this:

```
   trans_id  store_num  cust_id               bus_date          type    nxt_date    amt_received    type_rec
0   0000001        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment    11/5/2017              0     NaN
1   0000002        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Payment    11/5/2017              0     NaN
2   0000003        104   111111  10/5/2017 12:00:00 AM       Received   11/5/2017          10.00     NaN
```

Is there a way with merg/join/concat that this is feasible?
Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set all applicable values of amt_received to 0 after the merge?

```
merged = pd.merge(df_td, df_ld, how='inner', on=['cust_id','store_num'])
merged.loc[merged.type_y != 'Received','amt_received'] = 0

    cust_id nxt_date    store_num   amt_received    type_x  trans_id    bus_date    type_y
0   111111  11/5/2017   104         0.0                     1       10/5/2017   Payment
1   111111  11/5/2017   104         0.0                     2      10/5/2017    Payment
2   111111  11/5/2017   104         10.0                    3      10/5/2017    Received
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your reply. I spent the weekend fiddling with this as I like your thought process. The problem that I am running into is that my actual dataframe has more then one status under type_y. Therefore some items with unrelated status types not outlined in my original dataframe are being zero'ed out. I appologize for not adding this as I was hoping there was an argument I was missing in the pd.merge function. Is there another possible way to go about your suggestion that would avoid those sub status types?

Comment: This worked although I was not able to find an easy way to deal with the sub status types so I needed to just break it down into separate lines.

Comment: @Prof.Falken, if you post some more examples of the data you have I should be able to help you out with it. Could you give me some examples of  what you mean?